# Count horizontal de cada columna mysql

Tags: mysql, count

Estoy realizando una consulta para hacer un informe, lo tengo casi terminado. Me falta mostrar horizontalmente los resultados de cada columna, la idea serie totalizar los resultados de cada columna.Esto lo puedo hacer con php, js y otro lenguaje que trabaje con datos. El tema es que lo quiero hacer con mysql.

```
 SELECT e.provincia,
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.estado='RECUPERADO' and t.id_recolector='1177' AND 
 t.fecha >= '2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  
 AS 'RECUPERADO',
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.estado='A-CONFIRMAR'  AND t.id_recolector='1177' and 
 t.fecha >= '2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  
 AS 'A-CONFIRMAR',
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.estado='NO-TUVO-EQUIPO'  AND t.id_recolector='1177' and 
 t.fecha >= '2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  
 AS 'NO-TUVO-EQUIPO',
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.estado='NO-COINCIDE-SERIE'  AND t.id_recolector='1177' and 
 t.fecha >= '2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  
 AS 'NO-COINCIDE-SERIE',
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.estado='RECHAZADA'  AND t.id_recolector='1177' and t.fecha 
 >= '2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 
 'RECHAZADA',
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.estado='EN-USO'  AND t.id_recolector='1177' and t.fecha >= 
 '2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'EN- 
  USO',
SUM(CASE WHEN t.estado='N/TEL-EQUIVOCADO'  AND t.id_recolector='1177' and 
t.fecha >= '2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  
AS 'N/TEL-EQUIVOCADO',
SUM(CASE WHEN t.estado='NO-EXISTE-NUMERO'  AND t.id_recolector='1177' and 
t.fecha >= '2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  
AS 'NO-EXISTE-NUMERO',
SUM(CASE WHEN t.estado='NO-RESPONDE'  AND t.id_recolector='1177' and t.fecha 
>= '2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'NO- 
RESPONDE',
SUM(CASE WHEN t.estado='TIEMPO-ESPERA'  AND t.id_recolector='1177' and 
t.fecha >= '2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  
AS 'TIEMPO-ESPERA',
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.estado='SE-MUDO'  AND t.id_recolector='1177' and t.fecha >= 
 '2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'SE- 
 MUDO',
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.estado='YA-RETIRADO'  AND t.id_recolector='1177' and t.fecha 
 >= '2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'YA- 
 RETIRADO',
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.estado='ZONA-PELIGROSA'  AND t.id_recolector='1177' and 
 t.fecha >= '2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  
 AS 'ZONA-PELIGROSA',
 SUM(CASE WHEN e.empresa='POSNET'  AND t.id_recolector='1177' and t.fecha >= 
 '2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'POSNET',
 SUM(CASE WHEN e.empresa='ANTNA'  AND t.id_recolector='1177' and t.fecha >= 
 '2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'ANTINA',
 SUM(CASE WHEN e.empresa='INTV'  AND t.id_recolector='1177' and t.fecha >= 
'2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'INTV',
 SUM(CASE WHEN e.empresa='IPLAN'  AND t.id_recolector='1177' and t.fecha >= 
'2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'IPLAN',
SUM(CASE WHEN e.empresa='METROTEL'  AND t.id_recolector='1177' and t.fecha 
>= '2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 
'METROTEL',
SUM(CASE WHEN e.empresa='LAPOS'  AND t.id_recolector='1177' and t.fecha >= 
'2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'LAPOS',
SUM(CASE WHEN e.empresa='CABLEVISION'  AND t.id_recolector='1177' and 
t.fecha >= '2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  
AS 'CABLEVISION',
SUM(CASE WHEN e.empresa='CABLEVISION URUGUAY'  AND t.id_recolector='1177' 
and t.fecha >= '2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END)  AS 'CABLEVISION URUGUAY',
SUM(CASE WHEN  t.id_recolector='1177' and t.fecha >= '2020-11-03' 
AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-15%' AND e.provincia=e.provincia and t.estado 
IN('RECUPERADO','A-CONFIRMAR','NO-TUVO-EQUIPO','NO-COINCIDE- 
SERIE','RECHAZADA','N/TEL-EQUIVOCADO','NO-EXISTE-NUMERO','NO- 
RESPONDE','TIEMPO-ESPERA','SE-MUDO','YA-RETIRADO','ZONA-PELIGROSA') THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END)  AS 'TOTAL'
FROM express AS e
 INNER JOIN transito as t ON e.id_servidor=t.id
 GROUP BY e.provincia
```

Por ejemplo
[image: introducir el código aquí]

De que manera podria totalizar cada columna y colocar el resultado horizontal mente como que si de otra fila se tratara. Si no, tendre que seguir haciendolo con php. gracias!

Comment: php.. o tendrias que volver a hacer la query, con un group by el total de las filas... no existe un totalizador en sql porque esa no es la funcionalidad de sql....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [WITH ROLLUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) el cual retorna el total al final de la columna en donde se utilice una función de agregación.

Al final, en tu agrupación agregale dicho modificador:

```
GROUP BY e.provincia WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: gracias genio! sirvio